# Facebook and Unity3D JS injection difficulties

Tags: javascript, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'd like to display some HTML elements under my game on Facebook. Specifically, an image with a link to a website, but that's not the point of the question.

I understand what is required, and have successfully used the Application.ExternalEval() method, and the sample JS string provided by Facebook, to add some HTML text on top of the game itself.

I am following the information found on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/CUI/).

I have attempted the following permutations:

```
"var insertionPoint = body.children[0]; " + "body.insertBefore(headerElement, insertionPoint);";

"var insertionPoint = body.children[0]; " + "body.insertBefore(headerElement, insertionPoint.nextSibling);";

"var insertionPoint = body.children[1]; " + "body.insertBefore(headerElement, insertionPoint);";
```

After a couple of hours of frustrating trial and error, I have been unable to produce working JS injection code to display HTML immediately below the game itself on the canvas. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to do the same frustrating thing for a minute, here's what I've arrived at, had to use different techniques for different browsers.

```
string injection = "if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf(\"Firefox\") >= 0){;" +

            "var headerElement = document.createElement('div');" +
            "headerElement.innerHTML = '<img src=\"URLTOSOURCE" style=\"width: 100%; text-align: center\" />';" +
            "var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +
            "var insertionPoint = body.lastChild;" +
            "body.insertBefore(headerElement, insertionPoint);" +

            "}else{;" +

            "var headerElement = document.createElement('div');" +
            "headerElement.innerHTML = '<img src=\"URLTOSOURCE" />';" +
            "var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +
            "var insertionPoint = body.children[0]; " +
            "var unityPlayer = document.getElementById('unityPlayerEmbed');" + 
            "unityPlayer.parentNode.insertBefore(headerElement, unityPlayer.nextSibling);" +
            "var embedTag = unityPlayer.getElementsByTagName('embed');" + 
            "embedTag[0].setAttribute('style','display:block;width:1200px;height:600px');" +

            "};";

    Application.ExternalEval(injection);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - I tested on Chrome, and the Firefox code is all that's required, as well as properly setting the Canvas height. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
"var insertionPoint = body.lastChild;"
```

I post tricks and tutorials on my blog, check it out also for facebook sdk tutorials!

blog.bigfootgaming.net

Comment: This didn't work - the text just disappeared when I used body.lastChild.